# HttpPost Not working in asp.net mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, post, methods

I am new to asp.net MVC 4 . I just started demo app. Now my form is not posting here.

Here is my form

```
@model PartyInvites.Models.GuestResponse

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>InvitationForm</title>
</head>
<body>
    @using (@Html.BeginForm("InvitationForm", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <p>Your Name: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)</p>
        <p>Your Email: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email)</p>
        <p>Your PhoneNo: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PhoneNo)</p>
        <p>
            Will You Attend: @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.WillAttend, new[]
                      {new SelectListItem(){Text="Yes",Value=bool.TrueString},new SelectListItem()
                      {Text="No",Value=bool.FalseString}}, "--SELECT--")
        </p>

        <input type="button" value="Submit Invitation"  />
    }

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my Routing

```
namespace PartyInvites
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

And here is My Home controller

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            int hour = DateTime.Now.Hour;
            ViewBag.Greeting = hour > 12 ? "Afternon" : "Morning";
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ViewResult InvitationForm(GuestResponse guest)
        {
            return View("Thank You for Registration", guest);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ViewResult InvitationForm()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

I tried making all changes still **post** method is not invoked when i keep the break point. Pls help me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got just a button:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit Invitation"  />
```

but should be submit:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit Invitation"  />
```

P.S. remove @ symbol before Html.BeginForm you already defined one in "using"

Comment: <input type="submit" value="Register" />   i am using this.. but still its not working

Comment: @Mahima did you fix it?